# how can I add a auto subtitle system running in the background while the video is playing in android

Tags: android, video-capture, video-subtitles

I'm trying to implement automatic captioning while a video is playing. I've searched the internet but haven't found anything useful. Google has a plug-in called speech recognizer, but it does not work in the background while it is running, so you have to press something and talk and it blocks the video screen. Is there something free that I can automatically add subtitles to the video? or do you have a suggestion to do this ?